# API Platform difference between pagination_items_per_page and pagination_maximum_items_per_page

Tags: symfony, pagination, api-platform.com

In API Platform there exist two different settings where to me it is not clear what the difference is betweem them. This is `pagination_items_per_page` and `pagination_maximum_items_per_page`. In the [pagination documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/) it is extensively explained how you can configure these settings, but not when you should use it.

The default (global) configuration is as follows, as seen in the [configuration documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/configuration/).

```
api_platform:
    defaults:
        # The default number of items per page.
        pagination_items_per_page: 30

        # The maximum number of items per page.
        pagination_maximum_items_per_page: ~
```

I have also followed [this Symfony Casts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/pagination) about the topic of API Platform pagination, and there only the setting of `pagination_items_per_page` is used. This is suggesting that this setting is probably what you need in most cases.

When you set the `pagination_items_per_page`, does that not already set how many items will be returned anyways. When do you use `pagination_maximum_items_per_page`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since there is a setting to allow consumers of the API to change the amount of results via a query parameter, the `pagination_maximum_items_per_page` makes sense to make sure the user does not enter such a large value that your result is too large for your resources.

To allow pagination to be used as a query parameter globally, use the following configuration:

```
api_platform:
    defaults:
        pagination_client_enabled: true
        pagination_client_items_per_page: true
```

**I still have the open question** whether this is the only situation where you would use the `pagination_maximum_items_per_page`, or if this setting also prevents a very large pagination setting for a specific resource (with: `@ApiResource(attributes={"pagination_items_per_page"=9999})` for example) by overwriting that value if it exceeds the max per page setting.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/d62e86e9cfa2a7a4eba3029053ff65f43a10e1ce/src/DataProvider/Pagination.php#L134):

- `pagination_items_per_page` defines the default value of items per page, which can be overriden through the request
- `pagination_maximum_items_per_page` defines an upper bound of that possibly user-supplied value to avoid that the user DOS'es your system by requesting **all** items